# Help! Google is downloading books to me without my permission or involvement

Tags: google-play-store, settings

I noticed I had updates the other day, and was surprised to see that my phone (Droid X, Gingerbread) was downloading *Alice in Wonderland*. I did not ask for this book, and I don't want it on my phone taking up disk space. When I checked, I saw it had also downloaded Dickens' *Great Expectations* and (as if in some kind of smirking insult) Jane Austen's *Pride and Prejudice*. WTF?

Granted these books are in the public domain (i.e. free) but I really think *I* should be the one to decide what I want downloaded to my phone. Not Google.

What's worse, there is apparently *no* mechanism to prevent such downloads. The settings in the book and market apps make no mention of any of this.

Does anyone have advice on how to stop this behavior?

Comment: What app is doing this?  Can you provide a screenshot or something?  Where is it downloading them to?  Etc.  I currently have no idea what you could be talking about.

Comment: @Matthew: The new [Google Market](http://www.businessinsider.com/new-android-market-update-lets-you-rent-movies-and-buy-ebooks-2011-7) update is doing this.

Comment: This is the same reason I have the Twilight books on my phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is Google Books, this behavior should not carry on past these few books. *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, *Great Expectations*, and *Pride and Prejudice* are downloaded by default, to give a feel for the program and some reading examples. No additional books will be downloaded without your telling the application to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know this will be the end of it, but I still don't like that Google can do this, and wish they had *asked* me first. This is like being forced to eat a free sample of something at the supermarket.

Comment: Haha agreed, they should at least put it in the app description, or prompt before downloading.

Comment: Pretty sketch.  Thanks for the info jlehenbauer

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

haha I too just had the annoying google downloading books taking up space on my droid, here's how you delete them, to delete a book in your collection of books (including these automatically downloaded books), select the  Menu icon located alongside any book in your collection then select delete from library (problem solved! Hahaha! Google We Do Not Want These Books Forced Upon Us!). I found this info here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851658?hl=en-GB